# How to add dynamic timestamps for JS includes in static HTMLfile

Tags: javascript, html, caching, timestamp

So I have an interesting problem. I have a static site with some HTML files having javascript includes. Is there a way I can add a dynamic timestamp to these JS files in order to override caching and to have the latest version fetched.

Like:

```
<script async src="://main.lib.js?ts=1606903654"></script>
```

Earlier I could do this since the HTML was being generated dynamically using PHP. This is no longer the case and I am wondering how I can do this.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: This is one of the very few cases where I'd consider a `document.write("<script ...")` solution. You can also serve those files with a no-cache header by configuring your server appropriately.

Comment: is your head section still a PHP file? because then you can use a timestamp of when the file was last touched, as a version control, which would be updated each time you save the JS file with `filemtime()`

Answer (score 2):

Create your script element with JS and append it to HEAD.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "://main.lib.js?ts=" + new Date().getTime();
script.async = "async";
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: but this would always update the time, effectivly making sure that the file can never be cached right?

Comment: Exactly.Every time the page is called, the script is called with a new timestamp and cannot be cached.

Comment: If this is the actual intent (to never have cache on that file) then this answer is good - But I would prefer an answer using ajax to php, fetching the last modification time of the file, and use that a version number, so that you can still use cache when you not working on it. Then  the problem would cease to exist. But this surely answers the question, so have my upvote sir!

Answer (score 1):

Extending @alexP 's answer to enable the timestamp to remain constant for at max an hour.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "://main.lib.js?ts=" + Math.floor((new Date()).setMinutes(0) / 100000);
script.async = "async";
head.appendChild(script);
```

However, I'm not certain if caching will work because it depends on the headers you send with the js file. In simple terms, if the caching works then you don't need this timestamp